# In SPARQL, how to select predicateA provided predicateB doesn't exist?

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have simple data like this:

```
| s     | p  | o      |
|-------|----|--------|
| repo1 | v1 | high   |
| repo2 | v2 | medium |
| repo2 | v1 | high   |
```

Question is how to select `?level` such that if `v2` exists select `v2` else `v1`. The predicate `v1` is guaranteed to exist.

I tried

```
select ?s, ?level where {
       ?s v2 ?o_v2 .
       ?s v1 ?o_v1 .
       bind(if(bound(?o_v2), ?o_v2, ?o_v1) as ?level)
}
```

However that gets me subjects only for those that have both `v1 & v2`.

Comment: `select ?s ?level { ?s v1 ?o_v1 . optional { ?s v2 ?o_v2 } bind ( coalesce(?o_v2, ?o_v1) as ?level ) }`

Comment: It worked. Thanks for introducing me to "OPTIONAL & COALESCE" functions. I'm new to SPARQL, can you suggest a good guide for beginner? The official document is good but not beginner friendly.